# Accessing photos from AWS CloudFront

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

I have an S3 bucket called *my-bucket*. There is a folder inside *my-bucket* called *uploaded-photos*.

I can access the photos inside this bucket using the following URL:

*http://my-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploaded-photos/imag-1.jpg*

I have defined the following CloudFront behavior, so that all the .jpg images in the bucket are served from CloudFront.

[image]

After adding the images to CloudFront, I can access them using website root, i.e:

*[www.my-website.com/uploaded-photos/imag-1.jpg](http://www.my-website.com/uploaded-photos/imag-1.jpg)*

This is because I have the following CloudFront distribution:
[image]

I am not sure which one of these url I should use to server photos in my code? Does both of these URL get the photos from CloudFront edge location?

Comment: Either URL is fine to use. You can check this by using the one you prefer then checking your CloudFront access logs - assuming you enabled access logs.

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for your comment. I called AWS support and they told me if I use the path: `http://my-bucket.s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/uploaded-photos/imag-1.jpg` then I am bypassing the CloudFront

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of the two URLs in the green box.

You could [create an Origin Access Identity](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-restricting-access-to-s3.html) to block direct S3 bucket access, forcing requests to go through CloudFront.